# Can you take derivatives of Confidence Intervals?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, derivative

I have how defect density in a crystal change over time. 6 data points

I want to regress this with a 4th order polynomial. I can do this and obtain 95% non-simultaneous, functional prediction intervals.

However I want the derivative function of this density ultimately, with error. Can I simply take the derivative of the upper, bottom, and lower bounds separately and call it a day? Would these derivatives mean the same kind of 95% confidence intervals for the derivative function?

Comment: Is a confidence interval a continuous function? What variables is it a function of?

Comment: Hi. Could you add 2-3 formulas to your question? That will make it clearer to this forum. Thx.

Comment: @abalter By definition, the confidence interval is a function of the data.  Whether it's a continuous one depends on the procedure used to obtain the CI.

Comment: Briefly, no: differentiating the bounds has no clear meaning and is unlikely to produce what you want.  Your question can be addressed by adapting the technique for estimating derivatives in a quadratic regression at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/370178 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216189.